# Converted String to number but NaN pops up in the console.log instead of the number

Tags: javascript, numbers, nan

I am making a calculator. When I input the numbers I convert the string to a number in order for the function to operate but instead NaN pops up. How do I fix this? I consoled.log it to make sure it was a number and it is listed as a number when using typeof.

```
let currentValue = "";
let operator = "";
let previousValue = "";
let otherValue = "";

//numbers being inputed
numButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    handleNumber(e.target.textContent);
    preview.textContent = currentValue;
  });
});

function handleNumber(num) {
  if (currentValue.length <= 9) currentValue += num;
}

//operators being inputed
operationButtons.forEach((op) => {
  op.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    handleOp(e.target.textContent);

    preview.textContent = previousValue + " " + operator + " ";
    currentValue = preview.textContent;
  });
});

function handleOp(op) {
  operator = op;
  previousValue += currentValue;
}

//all clear
allClearButtons.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  currentValue = "";
  operator = "";
  previousValue = "";
  preview.textContent = currentValue;
  output.textContent = currentValue;
});

//equal button
equalButtons.addEventListener("click", () => {
  calculate();
});

//
function calculate() {
  previousValue = Number(previousValue);
  currentValue = Number(currentValue);
  if (operator == "+") {
    previousValue = previousValue + currentValue;
    console.log(typeof previousValue);
  } else if (operator == "-") {
    previousValue -= currentValue;
  } else if (operator == "X") {
    previousValue *= currentValue;
  } else if (operator == "/") {
    previousValue /= currentValue;
  }
  console.log(previousValue);
}
```

Comment: Note: `NaN` is of type `number`, but it indicates you parsed something that wasn't actually a number.

Comment: This may be the cause: `preview.textContent = previousValue + " " + operator + " "; currentValue = preview.textContent;`. Here you put some expression in the `currentValue` which produces NaN. For example, `Number('1 + 2 ')` will be NaN.